# Showing a pdf composed of other functions is valid

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be the CDF of a continuous R.V. and $f=F'$ be the PDF.

Show that $h$ defined by $h(x) = \frac{1}{2}f(-x) + \frac{1}{2}f(x)$ is also a valid PDF.

I did some computations to see that $h$'s CDF $H$ will approach $1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)dx \space= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}f(-x) + \frac{1}{2}f(x)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-x)dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}-F(-x) = f(-x) \Big|_a^b $$
$$=\frac{1}{2}F(-x)\Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \frac{1}{2}F(x)\Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(F(-\infty) - F(-(-\infty))) + \frac{1}{2}(F(\infty) - F(-\infty))$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(1) + \frac{1}{2}(1) = 1$$

With this, we have shows $H$ will approach $1$. However, how can we show $h$ is nonnegative, something (I would assume) is a requirement for a PDF. My thought would be that we would we have to show that $h$ is nondecreasing and show that $H$ is nonnegative as $x \rightarrow -\infty$

EDIT:

I just noticed that it is simple to see $H(x) = -\frac{1}{2}F(-x) + \frac{1}{2}F(x)$, which would make the computation of summing to $1$ simpler, and also can easily show that $H(x)$ is nonnegative as $x \rightarrow -\infty$. However, I am stuckj on showing $h(x)$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: $h$ is the average of two non-negative functions, each of which integrates to $1$, so $h$ is non-negative and integrates to $1$ and so can be a pdf.  $h$ and $f$ are not non-decreasing, though $H$  is non-decreasing and continuous since $F$ is.

Comment: oh yes, makes sense. thanks @Henry

Comment: Show that any convex combination of pdfs. is a pdf and show that if $f$ is a pdf, then so is $x \mapsto f(-x)$.